# Why function needs tibble as an argument even if it is not used inside function?

Tags: r, function, arguments, tidyverse, tibble

This code works as intended:

```
my_tbl<-tibble(var1=c("a","a","a"), var2=c("b","b","b"))

string_to_match_list<-list("b")

my_row<-my_tbl[2,]

my_tbl$var2[2]<-match_every_cell_start_and_modify_with_binary(my_tbl, my_row, string_to_match_list)

match_every_cell_start_and_modify_with_binary<-function(my_tbl, my_row, string_to_match_list)

{

  match_bool<-any(sapply(my_row, startsWith, unlist(string_to_match_list)))  #matches start only of the string by whole string.

  if (match_bool)
  {
    return(1)
  } else
  {
    return(0)
  }
}

my_tbl
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     b    
2 a     1    
3 a     b
```

If I remove argument `my_tbl` from a function `match_every_cell_start_and_modify_with_binary` code does not work, but I see that inside the function `my_tbl` is not used.

**QUESTIONs:**

1. Why function `match_every_cell_start_and_modify_with_binary` needs `my_tbl` as an argument?
2. Is there a way to remove `my_tbl` as an argument of the function `match_every_cell_start_and_modify_with_binary` and not affect its functionality?

Comment: Question 2: Yes, just change `<-function(my_tbl, my_row, string_to_match_list)` to `<-function(my_row, string_to_match_list)` and run the function definiton code to redefine the function as one with fewer arguments.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I was calling a function before I define it. Thank you.